# Proof verification: Prove the combinatorial identity $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\cdot {n\choose k}=n\cdot 2^{n-1} $

Tags: combinatorics, proof-writing, solution-verification, combinatorial-proofs

> Prove the combinatorial identity $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\cdot {n\choose k}=n\cdot 2^{n-1}  $$

I got this proof.

Suppose we are given $n$ distinct people. Now, consider the no. of teams with a team leader.

The RHS says " fix the team leader ( we can do it in $n$ ways) and then find all possible teams under that leader ( $2^{n-1}$ teams).

Note that $$k\cdot {n \choose k}=k\cdot \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}=\frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}=n\cdot {n-1\choose k-1}  $$

So, the LHS says " fix the team leader  we can do it in $n$ ways) and then find all possible teams of size $k$  under that leader which we can do in ${n-1\choose k-1} $ ways and then we sum it up over all possible $k$."

---

This proof was different from the given proof in the book. So can someone once proof read it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's correct, but it's a little more complicated than it needs to be.  The LHS counts the number of teams with size $k$, multiplied by the $k$ ways of choosing a team leader from any particular team, and then sums over all possible $k$.

Comment: @RobertShore yes thank you, I got it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comment, what you have done is algebraically correct, but it is just a few steps away from the expression on the RHS, since $$\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n-1}{k-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{k} 1^k 1^{n-1-k} = (1+1)^{n-1} = 2^{n-1}.$$  So I think you would agree that there is something of the combinatorial flavor of your proof that has been lost by performing the manipulation $$k \binom{n}{k} = n \binom{n-1}{k-1}, \tag{1}$$ as now both sides of the equation have the interpretation of first choosing the team leader in one of $n$ ways.

By contrast, the solution proposed in the comment (and probably your textbook as well), notes more directly that $k \binom{n}{k}$ counts the number of teams of size $k$, in which there are $k$ distinct choices for the team leader.  Thus the total number of teams is simply the sum of all $k$-size teams as $k = 1$ to $n$.

What the combinatorial argument boils down to is that the enumeration on the RHS first selects the leader, then finds the number of teams *of any size* that can be selected; whereas the LHS first selects the team size, counts the number of such teams without regard to identifying the leader--leading to the expression $\binom{n}{k}$--then identifies one member as the leader which leads to $k \binom{n}{k}$ teams of size $k$.  What makes your algebraic identity $(1)$ interesting is that it itself has a combinatorial interpretation:  the LHS is what we had just discussed, but the RHS corresponds to first selecting a leader among the $n$ people, then filling out the remaining $k-1$ team members among the $n-1$ people remaining, to form the full team of size $k$.